Extracting String from TListBox in C++Builder
How do I extract a string back out of a TListBox in C++Builder?
The ListBox was populated from a DB during runtime and I am needing the string value of the selected item. This box is single select. I am using C++Builder 12 CE.
I have tried to extract directly to TStrings* and String using Items[], but keep getting type mismatches or errors about abstract classes.

Since Items is a TStrings*, you can dereference it with * to use the TStrings::operator[]:
for (int idx = 0; idx < ListBox1->Count; ++idx) {
  auto str = (*ListBox1->Items)[idx];
  // do something with str
}

Or you can access the TStrings::Strings[] property:
auto str = ListBox1->Items->Strings[idx];

Or access operator[] with ->:
auto str = ListBox1->Items->operator[](idx);

Use the TListBox::ItemIndex property to get the index of the selected item:
if (int idx = ListBox1->ItemIndex; idx == -1) {
  // no item selected
} else {
  auto str = (*ListBox1->Items)[idx];
  // ...
}


There is no good reason to ever use Items->operator[](idx) over Items->Strings[idx]. As for operator*, I would opt for using an extra pair of parenthesis, eg: (*(ListBox1->Items))[idx], just to make it crystal clear that Items is the one being dereferenced and not ListBox1.

@RemyLebeau Thanks for the improvements! Yeah Items->operator[](idx) is probably rarely useful unless there's some meta / template programming going on. Not a normal case, I agree. ... and sure, operator precedence can be tricky to remember so extra parenthesis rarely hurts.

Thank you! Somehow I had missed going one level deeper to find "Strings". That information was what I needed.

@DavidKarnes You're welcome!
